Scatter plot legend with colors for a string attribute in complex dataframe using Matplotlib (Python)
I have a dataframe with thousands of depth values (y) and associated porosity values (x) and layer name (layer). I've created a scatter plot of the y and x values and want to color the symbols by layer. A simple example below:
#Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create Data
data = {'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'layer' : ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

#Plot Data
plt.scatter(df['x'],df['y'])
plt.show()

y   x layer

0   1   1     a
1   2   2     a
2   3   3     a
3   4   4     b
4   5   5     b
5   6   6     b
6   7   7     c
7   8   8     c
8   9   9     c
9  10  10     c

I need a simple way to color the symbols by layer and create a legend.
I was able to color the symbols using multiple methods, e.g., adding a color attribute to the dataframe by layer. However, I have failed to create a good legend for the color symbols of layer name. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks Tino D! Seaborn is a really simple way to solve my problem.

I'll post here some approaches that you can use to do this.
We start by defining our dataframe:
data = {'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'layer' : ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Matplotlib approach
You have the data, get subsets of the dataframe and plot that with a label.
Code looks like this:
layerColours = {'a': 'blue', 'b': 'green', 'c': 'red'} # map the letters to a color, can be automated
plt.figure()
for layer in df['layer'].unique(): # group by layer
    subDf = df[df['layer'] == layer] # get subset of dataframe
    plt.scatter(subDf['x'], subDf['y'], label=layer, color=layerColours[layer]) # plot
# add labels and such
plt.xlabel('Porosity (x)')
plt.ylabel('Depth (y)')
plt.title('Scatter Plot Colored by Layer with matplotlib')
plt.legend(title='Layer')
plt.grid()

Plot looks like this:


With Seaborn
Seaborn offers you the ability to plot data in a dataframe with in a very convinient way. For this, you can use this:
plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='layer', s=100)
plt.xlabel('Porosity (x)')
plt.ylabel('Depth (y)')
plt.title('Scatter Plot Colored by Layer')
plt.legend(title='Layer')
plt.grid()

The results:


With Pandas
Techinically, the following lines should work:
plt.figure()
df.groupby("layer").plot(x='x', y='y', ax= plt.gca(), kind='scatter')

However, this does not change the colour of the scattered points:

Using kind="line" automatically changes the colour:

Am not sure if this can be done in pandas, at least with the version that I have...
Might update this part of the answer later...
